# heroku - dependency issue causing Scala Play build to fail on heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework

I'm a bit of newbie to the Scala and the Play framework (2.6.x).  See `git push heroku master` failure screenshot below.

I'm requiring the [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) dependency in `build.sbt` (the first one):

```
libraryDependencies += "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.11.3"
libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test
```

And using it in my controller:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document

...

val res = scala.io.Source.fromURL(data.url)("ISO-8859-1").mkString
val s = Jsoup.parse(res).title
```

In addition I attempted to use it as an [unmanaged dependency](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SBTDependencies) by adding it to the lib/ folder, though I still get the same Heroku error.

Interestingly, the app works OK and without errors locally.  Is there something I'm missing?  Thanks.

Edit:

Beginning of build log:
[image]

Failure:
[image]

Comment: I have troubles replicating this. E.g., when I push my Scala Play app to Heroku, I see no such thing as `compilePlatBinaryScala`. My build starts with `remote: -----> Play 2.x app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Running: sbt compile stage` What about yours? Please post whole build log.

Comment: Are you using gradle for build?

Comment: Yes.  I've posted the screenshots above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, that you created Play project from a template. [Initial template](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-seed.g8/tree/2.6.x/src/main/g8) contains both `build.sbt` but also gradle build (`build.gradle`, `gradlew`, `gradlew.bat`. Locally, you use `sbt` for compilation. However, Heroku picks up Gradle build.

**Problem**: You added the dependency only to `build.sbt`, but not into `gradle.build` file.

If you do not really need Gradle, than I suggest to delete Gradle build files from your repository and try to push again.

If you want to keep Heroku using Gradle, than you have to maintain both types of build files.

There also probably is a way how to instruct Heroku to use `sbt` as preferred choice.

Comment: If I'd like to keep gradle, do simply add a line to `dependencies`?  Something like `play 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'` (which didn't work btw).

Comment: Hmm, `play "org.jsoup:jsoup':1.11.3"` works for me. Than I run `gradlew.bat compilePlayBinaryScala`. What did not work ? Any error received ?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific.  It looks like the build is not failing, but when I visit the url, all I see is a page with `An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command`.  Logs don't say anything, just `Release v2 created by user...`

Comment: Yes,  I know,  you now need to setup your heroku procfile

Comment: But that should be a new question. Btw,  did my answer solve your compilation problem?